# Dynamic of a particle with constant speed on the level set of a function

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, differential-equations

## Background

The dynamics of a particle $x_t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ moving with constant speed $\|\dot{x}_t\|$ on the level set
$$
\mathcal{M} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f(x) = c\} \qquad \qquad c\in\mathbb{R} \text{ fixed}.
$$
of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
    \dot{x}_t &= v_t \\
    \ddot{x}_t &= -\frac{v_t^\top H_f(x_t) v_t}{\|\nabla f(x_t)\|^2}\nabla f(x_t)
\end{align}
$$
where $\nabla f$ and $H_f$ are the gradient vector and Hessian matrix of $f$ respectively.

## Question

What does the dynamic become when $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$ and Jacobian $J_f(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ having full row rank?

Comment: **Derivation of dynamics for univariate case**: Essentially comprises these steps:
- Gradients are perpendicular to level sets and since $\|x_t\|$ is constant, velocity is parallel to acceleration $\dot{x}_t\perp \ddot{x}_t$. Hence we write $\ddot{x}_t = \lambda_t \nabla f(x_t)$.
- Differentiate $f(x_t) = c$ twice to obtain the condition
$$
\dot{x}_t^\top H_f(x_t) \dot{x}_t + \nabla f(x_t)^\top \ddot{x}_t = 0
$$
- Use the parallelism condition in the equation above
$$
\dot{x}_t^\top H_f(x_t) \dot{x}_t + \lambda_t \|\nabla f(x_t)\|^2 = 0
$$
- Solve for lambda

Answer (score 1):

Let's write with a notation using components $f_m(x_n(t)) = c$, to avoid misunderstanding with abstract notation (since order-3 tensors appear) and evaluate:

- first order derivative:
  $0 = \dfrac{d f_m}{d t} = \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n} v_n$
- second order derivative:
  $0 = \dfrac{d^2 f_m}{d t^2} = v_k \dfrac{\partial^2 f_m}{\partial x_k \partial x_n} v_n + \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n} a_n$

and thus

$\dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n} a_n = - v_p \dfrac{\partial^2 f_m}{\partial x_p \partial x_n} v_n$.

We now multiplicate by $\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_q}$ to get

$\dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_q} \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n} a_n = - \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_q}  v_p v_n \dfrac{\partial^2 f_m}{\partial x_p \partial x_n}$.

If constraints are independent, on the left-hand side we have a invertible matrix.

I made no use of the assumption $|\mathbf{v}| = \text{const}$. Maybe this expression get simpler

Answer (score 1):

I use vector and matrix notation
\begin{align*}
&f(x)=c\\
&v_f=\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{=J}\dot x=0\\
&a_f=J\,\ddot{x}+\frac{\partial v_f}{\partial x}\dot{x}=0
\end{align*}
multiply with $~J^T~$
\begin{align*}
&a_f=\underbrace{[J^T\,J]}_{A}\,\ddot{x}+J^T(\frac{\partial v_f}{\partial x}\dot{x})=0\quad \Rightarrow\\
 &\ddot{x}=-A^{-1}\,J^T\,\left(\frac{\partial v_f}{\partial x}\dot{x}\right)
\end{align*}

where

$~x~(m\times 1)~$ column vector

$~f~(n\times 1)~$ column vector constraint equations

$~J~(n\times m)~$ matrix with rang m